# Binding DataContext to UserControl.Resources ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

i want to Create my ViewModel in the UserControl.Resources, and it should set the Property Memory from the DataContext of the Control
I added this to the UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vms:VMMemoryViewer Memory="{Binding Content}" x:Key="VMViewer"></vms:VMMemoryViewer>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Memory is a DependencyProperty defined as followed:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MemoryProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Memory), typeof(IMemory), typeof(VMMemoryViewer),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMemoryChanged)));
```

The `DataContext` of the Control is set correctly (I just printed a label with a binding to DataContext and DataContext.Content)

However, the Memory Property is not set.
I read the Error in the Console :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Content; DataItem=null; target element is 'VMMemoryViewer' (HashCode=44436086); target property is 'Memory' (type 'IMemory')

but i don´t have an idea why ....

Comment: `VMMemoryViewer` seems to be a view class, not a view model class. You shouldn't have that in a resource dictionary, at least not outside a Style or DataTemplate.

Comment: VMMemoryViewer inherits from DependencyObject

Comment: That looks odd. Why don't you declare the Memory property in the UserControl?

Comment: DependencyProperty is only visible to the parent, example: if you set the memory property in vie model it will work, however you are setting it in a view, and view cannot access it as it is not the owner of the property.